# How to work with readonly props in REST API?

Tags: angularjs, rest, jackson

I have my REST API that exposes a resource made of some readonly fields. These fields are calculated automatically from the system and exposed in the JSON representation, and they are part of a **domain entity**.

I've succeeded in using the framework (*JacksonMapper*) annotation on the method that calculates the result, like:

```
@JsonProperty
public boolean isAnonymous(){
    //some logic
    return result;
}
```

Until these resource are used for read purpose, everything is OK. t

The problems arise when I have to work with write operations; `update` for example.

The framework I use for the client (*angularjs*), sends these fields to the update API when I search for a resource modify, and update it, for example:

```
function test(MyResource){
    MyResource.get({id: 0}, function(myResource){
        myResource.writeableProperty = 'modified';
        myResource.$update(function(res){
             console.log('everything went ok');
        });
    }
}
```

In this case the problem is the JSON sent by *angular* for the update:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "writeableProperty": "modified"
    "anonymous": true
}
```

In this case the deserialization of the JSON fail, due to the fact that the `anonymous` property doesn't exist in my **domain entity**.

How can I manage these readonly property, is it right to have the representation of the JSON that differs from what you have from the server and what you **have to** send to the server?

Or maybe it's better to use a different resource, making it possible to send that property, creating a related DTO in my application, and ignore the property on it (or send an error if someone try to change it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore this property on the server-side, you can use the [JsonIgnoreProperties](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.7/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class MyObject {
   ....
}
```

This will serialize only attributes that was declared in your class.