# Handle readonly properties in REST APIs

Tags: c#, json, class, rest

*NB. I am not sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407823/how-to-work-with-readonly-props-in-rest-api) is answering my question in case you are going to mark it as duplicate.*

A REST API I am working with has a method for creating a new `Person`. So I am sending a serialized version of my `Person` class to it (in a *POST* request):

```
public class Person
{
   public long Id;
   public string Name;
   public string Surname;
}
```

The problem is that `Id` is a readonly value and the API returns an error saying "*You are not allowed to set a value for Id*" which is quite reasonable. And as we know, when we create a new instance of the above class, `Id` will be set to zero. So API will think I am dictating a value for `Id`.

How can I modify my class so that I can use it both to

1. Create a new `Person`
2. Get a list of all `Person`s / Get a specific `Person` by `Id`

?

Comment: Why don't you split commands from queries (CQS). That way your contract contain only what is really needed.

Comment: What's the `REST API` framework you're using?

Comment: Your code doesn't say `Id` is readonly. Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: @Michael I am using `RestSharper`.

Comment: @KosalaW No, My code doesn't. Because later I want to use the same class to get a Person by Id as well. It's the API that answers like that.

Comment: @Disasterkid try to put `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute on `Id` property. As per [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802479/how-do-i-ignore-properties-when-using-restsharp-serialization) for `JsonSerializer` `[Scriptignore]` attribute is the one to use. Couldn't find anything to confirm that's the defaul serializer for `RestSharper` thou.

Answer (score 0):

Your entity class should be like this.

```
public class Person
{
   public int? Id {get;set;};//you can use long if you want
   public string Name {get;set;};
   public string Surname {get;set;};
}
```

Then you need a repository class to handle Add/Update/GetAll/Delete kind of operations. If you are familiar with repository patterns use them here.

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    public void Add(Person person)
    {
        //your add customer method
    }

    public List<Person> GetAll()
    {
        //your get all persons method
    }

    public Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        //your get person method
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. But again when I am using the Add function, the Id will be set to zero and the API will complain. Isn't that so?

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. Use a Nullable int then. See my updated answer. So you can send `null` for the `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the API should be able to handle this. Using a `0` to indicate "no value yet" for a new entity is quite reasonable.

Another option would be to use `Nullable<int>` for the Id, in which case `NULL` would indicate "no value yet".

(Also, you should really use properties instead of fields.)

```
public class Person
{
   public int? Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

However I don't think this is a better option than just using `0`.

If the API keeps complaining (I.E. it won't accept a `NULL` value, either), you can define a new class just for adding a new person.

```
public class NewPerson
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So strange that this API complains again that the value is null! Apparently it wants the request to not have an Id parameter to begin with.